# Is it possible to extend Javascript function arguments' properties into local scope?

Tags: javascript, scope, requirejs

Is it possible to extend function arguments' properties into the local scope of a function? Take the following code:

```
function foo(a, b) {
  // apply some magic here to extend arguments' properties into local scope
  assert(bar == 'hello')
  assert(baz == 'world')
  assert(qux == 1234)
}

foo({bar: 'hello', baz: 'world'}, {qux: 1234})
```

Supposing I don't have control over how `foo` is called and that I have control only over its implementation, is there something I can do in `foo` that will make it unnecessary to prefix, say, `bar` as `a.bar`?

I realize this may seem crazy in such a contrived example, so let me explain my overall objective. I want to use *requirejs* in such a way that I don't have to prefix an imported module's members with the module name. For example:

```
requirejs(['mod'], function(mod) {
  assert(mod.blah()) // OK, normal
  assert(blah())     // needs magic to work
})
```

My reason for trying to accomplish this is that I have several files that in my opinion logically belong together in a single module but for reasons of convenience for development don't mix well in the same source file—e.g., production code and test code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while, but I discovered a way to do this. It's possible to extend objects into the local scope with the JavaScript `with` keyword. However, use of `with` is discouraged, as according to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with). But if one really wanted to extend the local scope anyway, here's what it would look like.

```
function foo(a, b) {
  with (a) {
    with(b) {
      assert(bar == 'hello')
      assert(baz == 'world')
      assert(qux == 1234)
    }
  }
}

foo({bar: 'hello', baz: 'world'}, {qux: 1234})
```

Answer (score 2):

> My reason for trying to accomplish this is that I have several files that in my opinion logically belong together in a single module

Ah, we've got an XY-problem :-) Since there is no kind of magic like this in js (apart from just making all module properties global variables - certainly not what you want), you will need another solution.

Mixing `a` and `b` into a single module is simple by using an `extend` method. With jQuery, it could look like

```
var c = $.extend({}, a, b);
```

but you can do it with a simple for-in-loop as well. You even might declare it as an own requirejs module, depending on a and b and returning c; so you would only need to request c.

> for reasons of convenience for development don't mix well in the same source file

There might be other possibilities by using a build tool that combines the several development file into one (huge) production file. Not sure if that is applicable in your case.

Comment: Ah, interesting—I'll look into `extend`ing. As for using a build tool, I'd prefer not to.

Comment: OK, using `extend` works well for code *outside* `a` and `b`, but what I want is for code *inside* `a` to be able to use stuff in `b` without a prefix, and for stuff *inside* `b` to be able to use stuff in `a` without a prefix.

Comment: Uh, that's only possible if they are in the same scope. You really should look for a tool that automatically combines the two files.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say something like that.